# If else condtion using terrafrom modules

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I want to create an if else condition in my code. Let's say I want to provision a server, I just want to make sure if (name = abc or name=xyz) & (type=pqr) then my instance type=jkl.

I am unable to set up such a condition in my variables.tf file.
PS: I am a newbie in Terraform(2hrs old).
thanks

here's an example. I want instance_type to automatically pick up a value "pqr"

testabc.tf

```
module "testabc" {
 source ="/modules/xyz"
 name = "abc"
 hostname = "jdksnkfjsdn"
 instance_type = "hfd"
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example in code? Is it for a resource or just something related to variables?

Comment: @MarkoE I just updated my question with an example. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that is not possible the way you are trying to do it at the moment. The type should be based only on the name you assign?

Comment: @MarkoE Can't I use something like validation while defining this variable(instance type) in my variables.tf file. Example

variable "instance_type" {
  description = " testing abc"
  validation = {
    condition = (var.name == "abc" || var.name == "xyz")
  }
}

PS; not sure how to set the value of instance_type here

Comment: You can do a lot of things. It just depends what and where you want to do that. Variable validation can only work for only that particular variable, it cannot use values of other variables for validation.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have described what you want to achieve is not possible the way you are trying to do it. However, with some additional configuration, that can be done. For example, if you were to create variables for the root module, then you could do what you want.

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance name."
}

variable "type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Some type."
}
```

Then, in the module call, you would adjust the code to something along the lines of:

```
module "testabc" {
 source        = "/modules/xyz"
 name          = var.name
 hostname      = "jdksnkfjsdn"
 instance_type = (var.name == "abc" || var.name == "xyz" ) && (var.type == "pqr") ? "jkl" : "some other instance type"
}
```

The above example is using conditional expression [1] in terraform. It is similar to ternary operators in programming languages, as if the first part of the expression evaluates to `true`, then the value after the `?` will be assigned to the `instance_type` argument. If it evaluates to `false`, `instance_type` will be assigned a value after `:`.

In other words, if

```
(var.name == "abc" || var.name == "xyz" ) && (var.type == "pqr")
```

evaluates to `true`, then `instance_type = "jkl"`. If the above expression is false, then `instance_type = "some other instance type"`.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there way around for providing values(instance_type in my case) by default if the name matches to abc or xyz. I actually don't want to include this condition(instance_type = (var.name == "abc" || var.name == "xyz" ) && (var.type == "pqr") ? "jkl" : "some other instance type")  in modules. Thanks. Also, can I use precondition here? Like I'll first check if my var.name== "abc" || var.name=="xyz" then it will proceed to assign var.instance_type="pqr"

Comment: As I have mentioned in my comments, a lot of things can be done. Since your example is not really a clear one, I tried to answer to the best of my ability based on the information provided. If you have a real example, then I might be able to come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you know what and why you want to achieve this. Adding multiple conditions will make your Terraform script more complicated ([read more about Cognitive Complexity](https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf)), and then you may lose the advantage of using a declarative language like [HCL](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language#about-the-terraform-language). Yes, you may use it in MANY cases, but in general you may want to have a predictable state that's represented by an explicit Terraform scripts.

Now, you may want to practice more with declarative languages so you may rethink your logic to achieve what you want differently than by using a "conditional default value" which is not possible with Terraform.

From your other question ([terraform modules if else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282924/terraform-modules-if-else-condition)), I see the following:

```
if (stack == dev | stack == staging ) & type = xyz):
  instance_type =m5.large
else:
  instance_type= anything_else
```

You can make it easier to something like (in pseudo-code):

```
if (stack != "prod" && type == xyz):
  instance_type =m5.large
else:
  instance_type= anything_else
```

And this would make your module:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance name."
}

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance environment"
}

variable "type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Some type."
}

module "testabc" {
 source        = "/modules/xyz"
 name          = "${var.environment}-${var.name}"
 hostname      = "jdksnkfjsdn"
 instance_type = (var.environment != "prod"  && var.type == "pqr") ? "jkl" : "some other instance type"
}
```

---

Or, you can have multiple [`*.tfvars` files](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) where you set values for your variables, so you would have configuration like:

```
# dev.tfvars

name = "my dev instance name"
type = "my-dev-instance-type"
```

and

```
# prod.tfvars

name = "my production instance name"
type = "my-prod-instance-type"
```

Then your module would look like:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance name."
}

variable "type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Some type."
}

module "testabc" {
 source        = "/modules/xyz"
 name          = var.name
 hostname      = "jdksnkfjsdn"
 instance_type = var.type
}
```

And when applying you pass the [`-env-file` parameter](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) like:

```
terraform apply -var-file="dev.tfvars"
```

---

If none of these approaches is not suitable for you, please refer to [@Marko E's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75244198/5078746) since the [values in the `default` argument should be known before](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#default-values), and they shouldn't refer to something else in the configuration.

Also, you may have a look at [`local values`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) where you can define assign an object or result of an expression to a local variable:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance name."
}

variable "type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Some type."
}

locals {
  isSomething = (var.name == "abc" || var.name == "xyz" ) && (var.type == "pqr")
}

module "testabc" {
 source        = "/modules/xyz"
 name          = var.name
 hostname      = "jdksnkfjsdn"
 instance_type = local.isSomething ? "jkl" : "some other instance type"
}
```